# Spring boot test starts Application

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have written simple Spring boot command line application. I am implementing the unit test but I have figured out that the application is run as well. How to stop it?

*Main app*

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
  @Bean
  public CommandLineRunner demo(TransactionLogRepository repository) {
    return (args) -> {
        log.info("Application starts");
```

*Test*

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ApplicationTests {

  @Autowired
  private ComputeBrand normalizer;

  @Test
  public void test() {
    log.info("Test starts");
```

*Logs*

```
16:27:12.791 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner - SpringJUnit4ClassRunner constructor called with [class ApplicationTests]
2018-06-21 16:27:14.874  INFO 40980 --- [           main] .v.c.ApplicationTests : Starting ApplicationTests on DSCX516258 with PID 40980 (started by leos.literak
2018-06-21 16:27:14.877  INFO 40980 --- [           main] .v.c.ApplicationTests : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-06-21 16:27:14.939  INFO 40980 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@13f17eb4: startup date [Thu Jun 21 16:27:14 CEST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-06-21 16:27:22.485  INFO 40980 --- [           main] .v.c.ApplicationTests : Started ApplicationTests in 8.45 seconds (JVM running for 11.151)
2018-06-21 16:27:22.513  INFO 40980 --- [           main] c.a.p.v..Application  : Application starts
2018-06-21 16:27:23.373  INFO 40980 --- [           main] c.a.p.v.c.ApplicationTests : Test starts
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Working as intended. From testing documentation: "Spring Boot provides a `@SpringBootTest `annotation, which can be used as an alternative to the standard spring-test `@ContextConfiguration` annotation when you need Spring Boot features. The annotation works by creating the ApplicationContext used in your tests through SpringApplication. " https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html

Comment: I want to have all the contexts initialized. But I do not see in this sentence that the app is run. Can I avoid it somehow? E.g. write the test differently that the context is there but the application method is not executed?

Answer (score 0):

I have created following workaround:

*application.properties*

```
 unitTest=false
```

*Application*

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    @Value("${unitTest}")
    boolean unitTest = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner processTransactions(TransactionLogRepository repository) {
        return (args) -> {
            if (unitTest) {
                return;
            }
```